# Find the remainder of $7^{6n+2}+5^{18n+15}$ left dividing by $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$
7^{6n+2}+5^{18n+15}
$$
find the remainder left dividing by $9$. I can solve this if you say the relevant topic to consider.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: Maybe reasonable starting point could be: What is $7^2\bmod 9$ and $7^3\bmod9$? Can you get from that also $7^6 \bmod 9$? And you could try similar things with powers of $5$.

Comment: Also if you know [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), the fact that $\varphi(9)=6$ could help you.

Comment: Hint $7^{6n} mod  9 = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all with the use of Euler's theorem we have that : $5^{6}=5^{\phi(9)}\equiv 1 \mod 9$ ( $(5,9)=1$ ) .

1. $7^{6n+2}=7^{6n}\cdot 49\equiv 4\cdot [(-2)^{6}]^{n}\equiv 4\cdot 64^{n}\equiv 4\mod 9$
2. $5^{18n+15}\equiv (5^{6})^{3n}\cdot (5^{6})^{2}\cdot 5^{3}\equiv -1 \mod 9$

So finally we got that $7^{6n+2}+5^{18n+15}\equiv 3\mod 9$

Comment: Did you mean Euler's theorem?

Comment: Sure, I''ll fix it

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\bbN}{\mathbb{N}}$$\newcommand{\digsum}{\text{digitsum}} \DeclareMathOperator{\bbO}{\mathbb{O}} \DeclareMathOperator{\bbE}{\mathbb{E}}$$\blacksquare$ **Notation:** Let us denote:

- $\bbO := $ the set of all odd natural numbers
- $\bbE := $ the set of all even natural numbers

---

At first, note that $$ 5^{18n + 15 }= 125^{6n + 5} \equiv (-1)^{6n + 5} \bmod 9 \equiv -1 \bmod 9 \quad [\text{as } 6n + 5 \in \bbO ~\forall~n \in \mathbb{N}] $$

---

**Lemma:** For any $a \in \bbN$ and $n \in 3\mathbb{Z}$, The following is satisfied.
$$ a^{n} \equiv -1/0/1 \bmod 9 $$
*Proof:* If $n \in 3\mathbb{Z}$, then $n = 3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we have that $$ a^{3k} \equiv \begin{cases} 0 \bmod 9 & \text{if } (a \bmod 9)  \text{ is of the form } 3m\\
1 \bmod 9 & \text{if } (a \bmod 9) \text{ is of the form } 3m + 1 \\
(-1) \bmod 9 & \text{if } (a \bmod 9) \text{ is of the form } 3m + 2 \end{cases} $$
Hence, proved!

---

Again, by **Lemma** we have that $$ 7^{6n + 2} = 49 \cdot 7^{6n} \equiv 4 \bmod 9 $$
Thus we finally have that
$$ 5^{18n + 15} + 7^{6n + 2} \equiv 3 \bmod 9 $$